# How to plot candles selectively using plotcandle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to find a way to plot candles only when that candle is a high-peak candle.

Lets say I compute if the candle is high peak or not via

```
is_high_peak = (high[1] > high[2]) and (high <= high[1])
```

Would it be possible to use `plotcandle` such that it only display the candles that `is_high_peak` is true for them?

Basically I only want to see the candles with an arrow above them

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way to manage that:

```
is_high_peak = (high[1] > high[2]) and (high <= high[1])

plotcandle(is_high_peak ? open : na, is_high_peak ? high : na, is_high_peak ? low : na, is_high_peak ? close : na, "Your selective plot candle")
```

Comment: The main issue is that it display the next candle not the one that peaks happen on it. Somehow an offset should be introduce there, which I am not sure how.

Comment: I see.That is unfortunately impossible to accomplish with plot functions. These work strictly on current bars and cannot draw "backwards". Your best tool for such cases is a label.